# Export ExactTarget single record to CSV files

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, extension

I would like to export a single row from a Data Extension to CSV in FTP. Once the download is completed i would like to delete the same record from Data Extension.

Comment: Export a specific row from a data extension that contains other rows?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 1 will work to return just a random single row.

Unfortunately only SELECT statements are valid when creating a query activity, so you can't DELETE in the same spot.

This gets tricky, so you'll have to bear with me but it can be done.

You'll need 3 data extensions:

- One DE with the original data [table1]
- One DE with the 1 row of data you'd like to export [table-trim]
- One temporary DE where you move all your data (except the one row you just selected) [table2]

Step 1: *(overwrite results to **[table-trim]**)*. This selects a single random row from your first table.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * from [table1]
```

Step 2: *(overwrite results to **[table2]**)*. This step moves the data except the one row you exported into your temporary table.

```
SELECT * FROM [table1] 
WHERE
(key) NOT IN (
    SELECT (key) FROM [table-trim])
```

Step 3: *(overwrite results to **[table1]**)*. This moves back the data less the one row selected back to your origin table.

```
SELECT * FROM [table2]
```

To make sure I'm not just theorycrafting here I created these data extensions and queries to test it and it works. You'd just need to create a FTP activity to ship out the data from your [table-trim] DE and you're set.